# Nothing happening on doubleclick on a desktop-folder in Ubuntu 18.04.6

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, ubuntu-gnome, caja, doubleclick

since I am new here and have some issues with nautilus as standard filemanager I am trying to receive some help here. I have ubuntu 18.04.6 installed and it works correctly. My standard filemanager is nautilus. Today I intalled caja just to have a look on its performance. Since caja was not really faster, I uninstalled it. After that nautilus should be the standard filemanager again. Nautilus can be started in a terminal or a desktop-link. But if I try to doubleclick a mounted drive or the personal folder, nothing happens. No error message, simply nothing. Looks like ubuntu doesn't know what to do with a doubleclick on a desktop-folder. I was looking for a function to set a standard-action like "open with" but nothing is there. I can rightclick and say "open with other program" and choose nautilus. Then nautilus opens the folder correctly - but only once. Next time doubleclicking nothing happens again. Please help, or give me some clues! Thanks in advance! Harald

Comment: check out the first answer to [this question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333254/set-standard-file-browser-for-open-containing-folder) which describes how to set a default file manager. It's possible caja installed itself as the default file manager for your system and didn't get "unset" when it was uninstalled, so you may have to do that manually

Comment: I checked the other question and tried to edit the files as written in the solution. Most of the config-files like "mimeapps.list" is empty on my system. I checked on another machine with the same 18.04.6 installed, "mimeapps.list" is also empty there. Then I added 4 lines as written in one of the solutions, saved it and rebooted the system. Nothing happened, so I deleted the 4 lines and saved mimeapps.list as empty version like on my other machines where everything works properly. Is there any tweak tool to set standard-filemanagers in a GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who offered me solutions. Unfortunately nothing helped. The good news: 2 days later after doing nothing, it works again. I don't have a clue, how this happened or has been repaired, but it seems to have been fixed automatically. Since I don't know how to close a question, if anyone reads this, please close it for me if I can't. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

And if you click the box **remember this application**?
[image]

Comment: I wish I had this menu, this would be exactly what I need. I only can right click and choose open with other application (nautilus). But this works only once. There is no option to remember my choice in future.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Have you check this article? https://sourcedigit.com/13826-set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks to all who offered me solutions. Unfortunately nothing helped. The good news: 2 days later after doing nothing, it works again. I don't have a clue, how this happened or has been repaired, but it seems to have been fixed automatically. Since I don't know how to close a question, if anyone reads this, please close it for me if I can't. Thanks in advance.